# Issue to move file from one folder to another using window service, running as NetworkService

Tags: c#, windows-services

I want to move .txt file from one folder to another when window service is starting up.

```
protected override void OnStart()
    {
        string sourceFile = @"d:\Source\file.txt";
        string destinationFile = @"D:\Destination\file.txt";
        File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);
    }
```

this code is working well when the **serviceProcessInstaller1** Accunt type is **LocalSystem**. If i change the **serviceProcessInstaller1** Accunt type is **NetworkService**, I will get an error **access to the path is denied**. Help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: Try changing the account type back to `LocalSystem`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is the user permissions in the machine. Try changing the permissions to the file and the folder and set them less restricted. I'm sure that if you set all permissions to all users, your service will work. But it's risky too.

In [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx), "File Access" section, you can read how to configure this permissions.

Comment: if Right-click the required file and then click Properties. In the Properties dialog box, I can't get Security tab.

Comment: The only situation that I know that it doesn´t appear is because you aren't the administrator of the machine... It's very rare